# Refactoring Common Logic in Multiple AWS Lambdas

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-lambda

I'm thinking about two ways to refactor logic shared across AWS Lambda Applications.

The first way is to refactor the logic into a private npm package and import the package in the different lambdas.

Pro

- Doesn't need to spin up extra lambdas

Con

- Each lambda will need to be manually updated to the latest package version when an update happens (is this true?)

The second way is to create another AWS Lambda Application and move the logic there.

Pro

- Each lambda will NOT need to be manually updated to the latest version when an update happens

Cons

- Multiple lambda invocations increase cost and latency.

Is there a better way to share logic across different lambdas?

Comment: If the logic is used by a lot and shared across Lambda, I would pick second.

Comment: @dhidy Thanks, I'm leaning toward that option a bit more now too. I can create another application, but instead of using the lambda resource(AWS::Serverless::Function) i'll replace it with a layer resource(AWS::Serverless::LayerVersion). Then i can use that layer in the lambdas that need it

Comment: Yes, the layer will do. just make sure you update the version every time you update your package.